# Online app/text editor to format stack exchange posts

Tags: stack-exchange

I am looking for a online markup text editor that can do the following -

1. Free to use.
2. Can auto save what I am writing.
3. Allows me to format posts like in SE. I mean if I use the content then the content would turn bold and similar other formatting strings.
4. It would not sell what I write to advertisers but let me save them in my account.

Please let me know if such app exists.

Comment: You would only use the posts for yourself (personal notes), or do you need the platform to do anything with your posts, such as making them public or share them with others?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul for myself and if they can be shared then that would be better.

Comment: FYI: Stack Exchange uses a dialect of [*markdown*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) as its markup language. You can search for "markdown editor".

Comment: https://stackedit.io/ might be useful for you